# Doubling a certain number and then subtracting 5 gives the same result as subtracting 10 from the number and then multiplying by 7. Find the number.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

Doubling a certain number and then subtracting 5 gives the same result as subtracting 10 from the number and then multiplying by 7. Find the number. This is Problem Solving with Linear Equations question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If $x$ is the number you have to find, then $2x-5=(x-10)*7.$ Your turn !

Comment: @Fred  I usually give full credit on a story problem for the correct equation.  I don't think there's a "turn" left.